Which HMAC algorithm does Google Authentication uses in TOTP?
I wonder which algorithm is used (HmacSHA256, HmacSHA512, other)? I tried to look into the information inside the QR code, but there is no algorithm parameter there.

It turns out that SHA1 is used by default.
